# Unable to find similarity of two triangles.

Tags: geometry

In the image below taken from article title "Trisection using Bisection", [here](http://www.lamath.org/journal/Vol1/trisection_using_bisection.pdf); the issue lies in proving that $ DH/DA = DH/DJ = DJ/DB = DA/DB = \frac{1}{3}$.

How the link has been taken to $DA$ is not understandable. Request how to get to the geometrical proof that infers from the triangle similarity below that the ratio $DH/DA =\frac{1}{3}$. It seems that there is help taken of algebra to find the shifted center of the circle $c2$, and the simple fact that $AD = \frac{AB}{4}$.

[image]

There is stated to be similarity between the triangle $DJB, DHJ$, which can have one of three options ($AAA, SSS, SAS$). 
[image]

Can only state that one angle is similar (i.e. $90^0$). Could find nothing else.

---

*Edit* Use is made of two facts: 
(i) $AD=DC, AC=CB\implies AD = DB/3$; 
(ii)$DJ=DA$, as both radius of circle $c1$.
As the similarity shows $DH/DJ=DJ/DB$, so the rest of the argument can be constructed easily.

Comment: Do you know that DHB is 90 degrees?  Because it is embedded in a semi-circle?

Comment: @fleablood My edit is there with no queries left. Thanks for your comment. I hope you meant angle $\widehat {DJB}$ is $90^0$, as it is formed in a semicircle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The triangles are similar because their angles are the same (AAA). They both have an angle of $90^\circ$, and share an angle at $D$ (so of course the third angle is shared as well).

Incidentally, the labelling of the vertices in your diagram is wrong: the second triangle should be $DHJ$, not $BHJ$.

Comment: Sorry, very silly of me. Thanks a lot for correcting this error based in labeling of vertices.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to realize that $\angle DJB = 90^\circ$ because it is subscribed in a a semi-circle (https://www.mathopenref.com/semiinscribed.html)

So $\angle DJH \cong \angle JBH$ and $\angle JDH \cong \angle BJH$

Comment: Seems you have taken similarity between a new pair of triangles, i.e. between $HDJ, HJB$ on the basis of similarity between triangle $HDJ, JDB$ & $HJB, JDB$. So, So $\triangle HDJ \cong \triangle HJB$.

Comment: "new" triangles?  So far as I can tell, they've existed forever.  Look, if $\angle DJB$ is right (because it is inscribed in a semi-circle) and $\angle DHJ$ and $BHJ$ are are right (because we were told by God that $HJ \perp DB$) then $\angle B$ is complimentary to $HJB$ and $\angle D$ is compliementary to $\angle DJB$ and $\angle B$ and $\angle D$ are complimentary.  So all three triangles are similar to each other.  It doesn't matter which pair you *want*.  THey *ALL* fit.